# Using v-model on a button?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When a button is clicked I wish to push it's `name` to an array. When the button is not clicked I want to remove it's `name` from an array.

I know how to do this with an `@click` that pushes/splices the array.

I would like to know if there's a simple way of binding the clicks of the button to the array, just like how a checkbox works with `v-model`. I understand you cannot use `v-model` on a `button` but if we were to make the `button` it's own component and use `v-model` on that...

`<custom-button v-model="myArray"></custom-button>`

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Remember that `v-model` is just syntactic sugar for `v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value"`. In `custom-button` just have a prop `value` and emit an event `input` with the new value.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that but it just overrides the value in the binded model, how can I get it to push to an array?

Comment: You need to send an Array as prop and $emit updated Array as input.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the structure for the custom-button components like:

```
    ...,
    props: {
     originalArray: {

        required: true
      }
    },
    data(){
    return {
      modifiedArray: this.originalArray.map(x => ({...x}))
      }

   },

  methods: {

     yourMethod()
      {
      //do your logic on the modifiedArray
      this.$emit('changed',this.modifiedArray);
    }

   }
```

then you could use it like:

```
<custom-button :original-array="this.myArray" @changed="newArray => this.myArray = newArray" />
```

Comment: If you change `this.modifiedArray` like that you will be modifying prop `originalArray` too, because it is a shallow copy.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```js
const CBtn = {
  template: '#c-btn',
  props: ['array', 'label'],
  data(){
    return {
      ncTimeout: -1
    }
  },
  computed:{
    arr_proxy: {
      get(){
        // shallow copy to not modify parent array indices
        return this.array.slice()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(){
        
        this.notClicked()
        if(!this.arr_proxy.includes(this.label))
           this.$emit('update:array', this.arr_proxy.concat(this.label))
    },
    notClicked(){
      clearTimeout(this.ncTimeout)
      this.ncTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{
        let index = this.arr_proxy.findIndex(v => v === this.label)
        
        if(index>=0){
          this.arr_proxy.splice(index, 1)
          this.$emit('update:array', this.arr_proxy)
        }
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  components: {
   CBtn
  },
  template: '#main',
  data(){
    return {arr: []}
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template id="c-btn">
  <button
   @click="update"
   v-on="$listeners"
   v-bind="$attrs"
  >
    {{label}}  
  </button>
</template>

<template id="main">
  <div>
  <c-btn label="1" :array.sync="arr" ></c-btn>
  <c-btn label="2" :array.sync="arr" ></c-btn>
  <c-btn label="3" :array.sync="arr" ></c-btn>
  {{arr}}
  <div>
</template>

<div id="app"></div>
```

So yes you can use v-model with in `model` option defined `value: [propName]` and `event: [eventName]` or the `.sync` [modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) with `'update:[propName]'` event.

Comment: Does not answer the question re: v-model

Comment: Do you have an example?